# Why finally block in exception is not working in client-server program?

Tags: java, exception, finally

I have run the code of Client-Server interaction. Ignore the part of threading, I know that doesn't work.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket socket = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("localhost", 3456);
                System.out.println("Connect Ho gaya");
                final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                final BufferedReader sr_receive = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                Thread sendMes = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                String send = br.readLine();
                                pw.println(send);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Send Message Problem");
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

                Thread recMes = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                String recieve;
                                if ((recieve = sr_receive.readLine()) != null);
                                System.out.println("Server:" + recieve);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });
                while (true) {
                    recMes.run();
                    sendMes.run();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this Client side program (without Server program running), I expect it to keep showing the exception until I run Server side program as it made it an infinite loop.

But on running it, initially it shows exception that it exits the program. And also when I remove the finally part it keeps showing the exception and an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `finally` block is throwing an exception. When this happens, execution exits the try-catch-finally-block, and the loop it's in.

The exception is probably caused by `socket` being null. This would happen if opening the connection in the `Socket(host,port)` constructor fails, and an exception is thrown without anything being assigned to `socket`. Adding an if-statement to check for this in the `finally` block would help.

It's also possible that `socket.close` is throwing an IOException. You would need to add another try-catch for that.

```
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```